# How to make inner shadow shape in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I am a junior high school student who is just starting to learn Android Studio Kotlin. I want to know how to make an inner shadow appearance in the android studio like this picture below, I have searched various solutions on the website but haven't found one-way that works :(, do I have to add some implementation to input the inner shadow?

[image: Button with inner shadow]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[you can create like this shape as drawable file and use it in your layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8svku.png)

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- background color -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#03A9F4" />
        <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<!--  left shadow -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:angle="180"
            android:centerColor="#00FF0000"
            android:centerX="0.9"
            android:endColor="#5C000000"
            android:startColor="#00FF0000" />
        <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<!--  right shadow -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:angle="360"
            android:centerColor="#00FF0000"
            android:centerX="0.9"
            android:endColor="#5C000000"
            android:startColor="#00FF0000" />
        <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<!--  top shadow -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:centerColor="#00FF0000"
            android:centerY="0.2"
            android:endColor="#00FF0000"
            android:startColor="#6B000000" />
        <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are libraries for creating such like UI called **neumorphism**.

1. [Neomorphic-FrameLayout-Android](https://github.com/4inodev/Neomorphic-FrameLayout-Android)

   implementation 'com.github.4inodev:Neomorphic-FrameLayoutAndroid:1.03'
2. [neumorphism](https://github.com/fornewid/neumorphism)

   implementation 'com.github.fornewid:neumorphism:{latest_version}'

[image]